# Hanging a 10Kg fixed frame projector screen without stud/joists

Tags: walls, hanging, projector

Using a Stud finder, I just can't find any stud which at the right location. Shall I just be able to hang this with plastic anchor bolt which comes with the projector screen. I saw someone asked about the similar question but with pull down projector screen which may has a bit difference

Comment: Would use plywood or 2x4s screwed into the joists and then screw the projector screen to the wood.  I hate it when the screen falls down at the good point of a movie.

Comment: I just can't find the stud/joists at the right location.

Comment: Use the plywood/2x4s to cross the studs.  You then have something in the right place.  If you mean you cannot find any studs that is a different problem than a stud not in the right place to hang the screen.

Comment: As I've said in at least one similar question, connect chains to hooks in the joists or studs and you can locate a screen wherever you like without depending on wall anchors. A long board is another option. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/104156/18078

Comment: are you hanging from wall or from ceiling?

Comment: Is your ceiling drywall?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use drywall EZ anchors. over the years I have hung many heavy loads on the drywall where I cannot find studs. I always use these instead of the anchors that come with the product. They are heavy duty, sturdy and if you use 2 or 3 of them each of them can hold up to 75lbs!! so that would be 150lb to 225lbs of weight. They are so easy to use you can screw them in using a regular screw drive if you dont have a drill

https://www.lowes.com/pd/E-Z-Ancor-4-Pack-Standard-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/1098799

[image]

Comment: This might work for a wall application, but I'd be a bit leery of using it for a ceiling install. We need OP to clarify.

Comment: @FreeMan op mentioned projector screen which usually goes on a wall :)

Comment: I've seen more than a few that hang from the ceiling.

Comment: @FreeMan I mentioned in the title it is a fixed frame projector screen. Who hanging a fixed frame projector screen from ceiling? pull down or motorized may be.

Comment: We've had a lot of people asking to do very unusual things, @ZooS. One never knows - it's why answering based on assumptions is dangerous around here...

Answer (score 0):

There are specially made anchors for that situation.

They can carry more weight or up to 50 pounds each.

The reason is they open up and spread the weight.

Starting from the left, is the best (for weight)

[image: anchors]